# Dictionnary Attack sometimes returns wrong password in C

Tags: c, encryption

I'm trying to build a program that uses a dictionary attack to crack passwords encrypted with DES (exercise for a class). 
I'm testing it by encrypting words that I know are in the used dictionnary with the crypt() function.

Sometimes it works, some of the time it returns the value right above or below the correct one and other times it returns nothing.
i.e. Trying to crack the hash of nonorthogonality returns nonorthogonal (which is just above it), trying to crack the hash of aba returns nothing. Some other words work (Remember that all these words are definitely in the dictionary I'm using.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

char salt[2];

int checker();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    //returns an error and exit if no or more than 1 hash was entered
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You must enter one password\n");
        return 1;


    }

    //Extracts the salt from the entered hashed password
    strncpy(salt, argv[1], 3);
    salt[2] = '\0';

    //opens the dictionnary file and gets it line by line
    FILE *dictionnary = fopen ("/Path/To/Dictionary.txt", "rt");
    char buf[256];
    printf("Using Dictionnary\n");
    while (fgets (buf, sizeof(buf), dictionnary)) 
    {   
        if(checker(argv[1], buf)==0)
            break;

    }


    return 0;
}

//takes the value of the password taken from the dictionnary, hashes it and compares it to the entered hash. Prints the unhashed password if they're the same


 int checker(char hash[], char* tocheck)
{
tocheck[strcspn ( tocheck, "\n" )] = '\0';
char* passwd = crypt(tocheck, salt);
if (strcmp(hash, passwd) == 0)
{

    printf("The password is %s\n", tocheck);
    return 0;       
}


else
    return 1;
```

}

I've tried it after removing the break statement and it's now returning both the incorrect password and the correct one that is right below it (i.e. both nonorthogonal and nonorthogonality), but it's still not working with some other ones.
Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: After going through the debugger, i figured it out. I was converting the new line character to a null character on the hash instead of on the value I got from the file. This was useless. New fixed code that works.
Thank you all for your help

Comment: Use a debugger (or print statements) to output the words being read from the file, the hashes being computed for each word, and what the comparison function returns. That should help identify where things are going wrong.

Comment: Also, turn on ALL your compiler warnings. Your checker function doesn't return anything when there isn't a match. This is undefined behavior (the program probably returns whatever garbage happens to be on the stack), leading to unpredictable behavior. This is probably the issue, and compiler warnings would have pointed this out.

Comment: You declare global variable `salt` with dimension 2, and then write to to third element (index 2).  This produces undefined behavior, but probably does not explain the actual behavior you observe.  (But, undefined.)

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the 2 errors that were causing undefined behavior and will play around with the debugger to see what's going on precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual page for `crypt()`:

> By taking the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters of
>          the key, a 56-bit key is obtained.  This 56-bit key is used to
>          encrypt repeatedly a constant string (usually a string consisting of
>          all zeros).

Bottom line: only the first 8 bytes of the key are significant to `crypt()`.  If your dictionary contained the (non-)word "nonortho" then you program should match it to the crypted version of "nonorthorthogonality", too.

As for failure to crack passwords you think you should be able to crack, pay attention to @AndrewMedico's comment about what function `checker()` (fails to) return in the event that it does not successfully match.  It is entirely plausible that it sometimes returns `0` despite not matching.